# Generic list view + site-wide data in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a view that perfectly fits the `ListView` in Django. Like this:

```
url(r'^$',
    ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
        context_object_name='latest_poll_list',
        template_name='polls/views/index.html')),
```

However I on the page of the view I also would like to display content from another model. This model contains only one row of data. It's sitewide and contains the footer-text page-title etc.

What's the best solution for this? Ideally I'd like to keep the generic-model approach.

Comment: You could add in your own template_context_processor: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods that will solve this issue. The view is definitely not the correct place.

**Template Tags**
One way to use [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) is as mini-views. Whether you are requesting data from another model, or rendering an included template.

Because you can also pass parameters into the template tag, they can be customized by the context.

**Context Processors**
For simpler information,[context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) work well. I wouldn't get too complicated with the data, as it is global and can slow down every request.

On an aside, I would also question your one-row model. My guess is that this is to allow user editing. If users access it, expect every possible way of screwing it up. For example, adding more rows. There are several Django applications for managing user-editable settings that might be useful. If the data isn't going to change often, I would make it an actual setting, or put it in a template snippet and {% include %} it.